# front page slider positioning bug

Tags: wordpress, themes, slider, positioning

Theme creator fixed a known bug on this template (google map plugin was breaking widget structure). Somehow this caused the front page slider to jump way to the right of page content. For the life of me can't figure out how to fix this, they have not responded and am on a deadline.

Any help would be much appreciated. Here is the style sheet: http://pastebin.com/myvUsbgZ Here is the site: http://mefo1.ecin1prod1lnx1.com/

Thank you,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is just a bandage over a deeper problem, but if you add `clear: both;` to the `slider1` style it seems to center image correctly.

Comment: Thank you Peter. A bandage is more than welcome now. Unfortunately this isn't working for me. Add to this? #slider1 {
    width: 960px; /* important to be same as image width */
    height: 280px; /* important to be same as image height */
    position: relative; /* important */
 overflow: hidden; /* important */
 
}

Comment: @Alex: Yes. I was using Firebug in Firefox to edit the CSS directly and it worked. Try making that edit and then do a *Shift-Reload* to make sure you aren't getting the CSS file from the browser cache.

Comment: hmm.. no luck but I really appreciate your help. :)